# MariaDB - embed function to automatically sum columns and store result?

Tags: automation, mariadb

it is possible to store a function IN the table to automatically sum a group of columns and store the result in a final column?

ie:

```
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| id | appleCount | pearCount | bananaCount | totalFruit |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| 1  |     300    |     60    |     120     |     480    |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

where the column `totalFruit` is automatically calculated from the previous three columns and updated as the other columns update.  in this specific application, there is ONLY going to be the one row.   it would be spanky-handy to be able to just push the updated counts and then pull the calculated total out.  i seem to recall reading about this ability somewhere, but for the life of me, i can't recall where...  :poop:

if there is not way to do this, that's cool.  but if there is...  :smile:

TIA!

WR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  But is it worth it?  It is simple enough to do

```
SELECT ...
    appleCount + pearCount + bananaCount AS totalFruit
    ...
```

See [*MariaDB Generated Columns*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/) for how to generate the extra column -- either as a real extra column or "virtual".  What version of MariaDB?--There are a number of changes over time.

(MySQL users: 5.7.6 has a similar [*MySQL Generated Columns*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).)

Comment: worth it? probably not. but i had this tiny project and thought 'what the heck'. plus it may be useful later. thank you!

Comment: and to answer your other question: MariaDB 10.2.7.  ;)